# Jenkins Job Rest API

Tags: jenkins

I'm using JenkinsAPI. When I get job objects, the number of build objects that can be retrieved on a particular job is limited to 10 (the number of builds displayed in the rest api of a job is limited to 10). I think, it's not a jenkins version issue, because I have two more running jenkins instances (older and newer) and they work properly (don't limit the number). Unfortunately, I can't figure out what's the reason by comparing them.

So, how can I configure the number of builds displayed in the rest api of a job?

The Jenkins version: 1.491
The older one:       1.447.1
The newer one:       1.531

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the REST API and parsing XML output, you shouldn't have that kind of limitation.
On my server (version 1.564), I'm able to retrieve ALL jobs (~100):

`http://192.168.0.1/jenkins/api/xml?tree=jobs[name]`